# AngularJS search name and count duplicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an issue with this application:

this application gets som data from a database containing some names.The user spouse to type a name if there is a match it shall print the name out and how many time the name is in the database.

here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Search for a Name Here</h1>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search Employee" ng-model="searchemp" />
     <table border="1">
         <tr>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Middle Name</th>
             <th>Last Name</th>
             <th>Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in empJson | filter : searchemp">
             <td>{{ x.firstname }}</td>
             <td>{{ x.middlename }}</td>
             <td>{{ x.lasttname }}</td>
             <td>{{ x.count }}</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/Home/getEmp'
}).then(function (response) {
$scope.emp = response.data;
    }, function (error) {
 });
});
```

here is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    /*

     */
    public JsonResult getEmp()
    {

        Database1Entities obj = new Database1Entities();
        List<empJson> toReturn = (from temp in obj.emps
                                  group temp by temp.firstname + " " + temp.middlename + " " + temp.lastname into x
                                  select new empJson()
                                  {
                                      fullname = x.Key,
                                      count = x.Count(),

                                  }).ToList();
        return Json(toReturn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //shopProducts.Where(p => names.Contains(p.Name))
        //               .ToList();
    }
}

/*

*/
    class empJson
    {
        public string fullname { get; set; }
        public String first { get; set; }
        public String middle { get; set; }
        public String last { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the database:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string middlename { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

sample of the list:

Meriel J Oscar,
Mike T Ree,
Mike T Ree,
Mike T Ree,
Mike brown,
Mike T Ree,
Robert Tah,

[When I run this code it shows like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAJiX.png)

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2rXh.png)

it spouse to be like

Mike T Ree 4

Comment: how your `empJson` looks like?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you want to filter rows based on name , but you already have count property for each row , can you post your sample `empJson` as well

Comment: I added the database

Comment: I added some example how is the data in the database

Comment: @SrinivasML are you still here?

Comment: Before search, does your ng-repeat render data correctly. Did you check the console of the browser?

Comment: @sina_Islam it shows Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8

Comment: Can you create a plunker with sample data or post screen of error

Comment: @SrinivasML how can I do that?

Comment: @SrinivasML I added an image of the error

Comment: @sina_Islam ,are you still here?

Comment: Yes @Meriel problem is in angular configuration. Does your ng-repeat render the data?

Comment: @sina_Islam How can I know that?  This is my first application with angular.

Comment: Can you please try the bellow one

<tr ng-repeat="x in emp | filter : searchemp">

Comment: Does your app.js contains only code which you pasted here?

Comment: @sina_Islam what should I try?

Comment: @SrinivasML Yes

Comment: Replace  <tr ng-repeat="x in empJson | filter : searchemp"> by <tr ng-repeat="x in emp | filter : searchemp"> and let me know are there any change.

Comment: @sina_Islam it shows this Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0AG%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3

Comment: @sina_Islam did you see the error?

Comment: Yes. You need to configure the angular correctly at your application. You need to do little R&D over internet. By the way if I get time I will set up the initial setup.

Comment: @sina_Islam Thank you I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting this output , try below running below code once , I am still confused where you have defined `empJson` in angular controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.empJson = [{firstname:' Meriel J Oscar'},
{firstname:'Mike T Ree'},
{firstname:'Mike T Ree'},
{firstname:'Mike T Ree'},
{firstname:'Mike T Ree'},
{firstname:'Meriel J Oscar'},
{firstname:'Robert Tah'},
{firstname:'Meriel J Oscar'}];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Search for a Name Here</h1>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search Employee" ng-model="searchemp" />
     <table border="1">
         <tr>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in emp=(empJson | filter : searchemp)">
             <td>{{ x.firstname }}</td>
              <td>{{ emp.length }}</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

to your layout page.

At Index.cshtml add

```
<h1>Search for a Name Here</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Employee" ng-model="searchemp" /><br /><br />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in emp | filter : searchemp">
            <td>{{ x.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.count }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And at the controller the method with sample data is

```
public JsonResult GetEmp()
    {

        //Database1Entities obj = new Database1Entities();
        List<empJson> json = new List<empJson> {
            new empJson {first="Meriel", fullname="Meriel J Oscar", count=1, last="Oscar", middle="J"},
            new empJson {first="Mike", fullname="Mike T Ree", count=4, last="Ree", middle="T"},
            new empJson {first="Mike", fullname="Mike T Ree", count=4, last="Ree", middle="T"},
            new empJson {first="Mike", fullname="Mike T Ree", count=4, last="Ree", middle="T"},
            new empJson {first="Mike", fullname="Mike brown", count=1, last="brown", middle=""},
            new empJson {first="Mike", fullname="Mike T Ree", count=4, last="Ree", middle="T"},
            new empJson {first="Robert", fullname="Robert Tah", count=1, last="Tah", middle=""}
                };

        List<empJson> toReturn  = (from temp in json
                                   group temp by temp.first + " " + temp.middle + " " + temp.last into x
                                  select new empJson()
                                  {
                                      fullname = x.Key,
                                      count = x.Count(),

                                  }).ToList();

        return Json(toReturn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: is there any way we can make the count dynamic? @sina_Islam

Comment: Yes we should but for that I need to make the whole Database.

Comment: No problem Thank you for the help